# Django Admin: Indent Model parent ForeignKey self relationship

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

Here is my model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "companies"

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Company: %s' % self.name
```

Is there a way to modify the `def __str__` method in order to display the children with a `-` or indent, depending on the relationship to it's parent? Like so:

```
Company A
- Company C
Company B
- Company D
- Company E
-- Company F
```

Comment: I strongly suggest to use the [`django-mptt`](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) package along with [`django-mptt-admin`](https://github.com/mbraak/django-mptt-admin).

Comment: I was using it and I understand the benefits in the long-term, but I'd like to stick with this workflow for now.

Comment: What you're asking is re-inventing `django-mptt` and `django-mptt-admin`. They work brilliant (I use them too, without any problem). On the other hand, I, somehow, have completed the `-` issue (prefix each `Company` with (or without) a dash (`-`) in the `__str__` method but still the `change_list.html` admin template has to be altered in order for the `Company`s to be appeared ordered.